# Django: how to get the second last object from database?

Tags: django

I have a model for news. I add news to the database with Django admin. Model `Post` consists of title, body and image.

On the `main.html` page of my project i have a carousel with 3 slides.
I already have some news in my database, and I want to display the last, the second last and so on **images** in that carousel.

My question is: **what code** should I add in **html** to display the last, the second last and the third last images?

```
<img src="???"> {# the last image #}
<img src="???"> {# the second last image #}
<img src="???"> {# the third last image #}
```

Comment: @bloodwithmilk negative index is not supported in Queryset(atleast not in Django 1.11)

Comment: @ruddra my bad, I confused Queryset object with something else...

Comment: bloodwithmilk, where should I use that code, and what should I add to the carousel slides?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
posts= Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
last_post = posts[0]
second_last_post = posts[1]
third_last_post = posts[2]
last_three_posts = posts[0:3]
```

But make sure to have atleast three posts or else it will throw index error

Comment: You need to put this code in the view, and pass these objects as context to template. Then you can use them to render your carousel

Answer (score 0):

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id') 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {
            'carousel_posts': self.posts[:3],
        }
        return context
```

Use this make a for loop over the `carouser_posts` keyword in your template and extract the information you need.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  {% for post in carousel_posts %}
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{post.image}}">
        <p>{{post.title}}"</p>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

**UPDATE**
Answer to your update. Using context keyword `carousel_posts` provided by our `HomePageView` we can access `post` objects one by one using for loop.

In template, assuming that your `Post` model has an image field called `image`.

```
{% for post in carousel_posts %}
    <img src="{{ post.image.url }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This was useful, thank you. You missed order_by('-id') after posts = Post.objects.all(). But now i just have to fix the carousel.